# How to define Subnet in Terraform for Azure CosmosDB

Tags: terraform, azure-cosmosdb, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to create Azure CosmosDB with Terraform Template. I'm able to create CosmosDB successfully but unable to add existing subnet details in terraform template.
I'm trying to add subnet as below, but not working. Can someone please help me how can I define subnet in terraform. Any specific version I need to use.

```
is_virtual_network_filter_enabled = true

virtual_network_rule {
    id = <MY SUBNET ID>
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What exactly did you try? What errors did you get?

Comment: Hi @Marcin I tried 
is_virtual_network_filter_enabled = true

virtual_network_rule {
    id = "subnetID"
  }

below is the error which I'm getting
Error: Can not parse "virtual_network_rule.0.id" as a resource id: Cannot parse Azure ID: parse "APSG-APP1": invalid URI for request

  on main.tf line 16, in resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "db":
  16: resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "db" {

Comment: Any update on this question? Is my reply helpful to you?

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse the below [template](https://github.com/sajeetharan/terraform-cosmosdb-azure),

```
## Azure resource provider ##
provider "azurerm" {
  version = ">= 0.12"
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "main" {
  name                = var.cosmosdb
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name  
  offer_type          = "Standard"
  kind                = "MongoDB"
  is_virtual_network_filter_enabled = "true"
  ip_range_filter     = var.ip_range_filter

  enable_automatic_failover = false

  consistency_policy {
    consistency_level       = "Session"
    max_interval_in_seconds = 5
    max_staleness_prefix    = 100
  }

  geo_location {
    location          = var.location
    failover_priority = 0
  }

  virtual_network_rule  {
    id                = var.vnet_subnet_id
    ignore_missing_vnet_service_endpoint = true
  }
  
}

#resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_mongo_database" "db" {
#  name                = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.main.name
#  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
#  account_name        = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.main.name
#}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the error message in your comment,

> Can not parse "virtual_network_rule.0.id" as a resource id: Cannot
> parse Azure ID: parse "APSG-APP1": invalid URI for request on main.tf
> line 16, in resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "db": 16: resource
> "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "db" {

I can reproduce this issue. It might be a problem with your subnet ID. Please check the subnet id you have passed to the terraform code. The `id` should be a resource id of the subnet instead of a subnet name.

```
  virtual_network_rule  {
    id                = "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxrg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/xxxxvnet/subnets/xxxSubnet"
   # ignore_missing_vnet_service_endpoint = true
  }
```

If you're trying to add an existing subnet, the subnet should enable the service endpoint for `Microsoft.AzureCosmosDB`.

```
service_endpoints    = ["Microsoft.AzureCosmosDB"]
```

Or you can add `ignore_missing_vnet_service_endpoint` to ignore missing service endpoint.